# FreeForm Express - receiving multiple emails

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, email

EE 5.2.5
FreeForm Express 1.7.6

I have a client with a working contact form that for every submission he receives two emails. I double checked the form admin settings and his email is only listed once.

Is there a way to stop the second email from being sent?

Comment: Do you confirmed with your client whether User Email id of contact form is not matched with Admin email address?

Comment: Are you notifying the sender as well? If using the "admin" email address that could result in duplication.